# Bottom footer based on bootstrap 4 and responsiveness

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

This footer is perfect for mobile **(ios and android devices)** also desktop but tablet have some  issue specially right bar ! How can I optimized responsiveness for tablet devices ? Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

```css
.mainfooter-area {
  background: #404044;
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.mainfooter-area h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "TrebuchetMS", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .mainfooter-area h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "TrebuchetMS", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .mainfooter-area {
    padding: 50px 0;
  }
}

.ll-footer-about {
  position: relative;
}

.ll-footer-about:after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 80%;
}

.ll-footer-about p {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #8b8b8b;
  font-weight: 300;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .ll-footer-about {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
}

.ll-footer-ourcompany,
.ll-footer-faq {
  position: relative;
}

.ll-footer-ourcompany:after,
.ll-footer-faq:after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 80%;
}

.ll-footer-ourcompany a,
.ll-footer-faq a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #8b8b8b;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.ll-footer-ourcompany a::before,
.ll-footer-ourcompany a::after,
.ll-footer-faq a::before,
.ll-footer-faq a::after {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.ll-footer-ourcompany a::before,
.ll-footer-faq a::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
  transform: translateX(20px);
}

.ll-footer-ourcompany a::after,
.ll-footer-faq a::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.ll-footer-ourcompany a:hover::before,
.ll-footer-ourcompany a:hover::after,
.ll-footer-ourcompany a:focus::before,
.ll-footer-ourcompany a:focus::after,
.ll-footer-faq a:hover::before,
.ll-footer-faq a:hover::after,
.ll-footer-faq a:focus::before,
.ll-footer-faq a:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.ll-footer-ourcompany a:hover,
.ll-footer-faq a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .ll-footer-ourcompany::after,
  .ll-footer-faq::after {
    border-right: none;
  }
  .ll-footer-ourcompany {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .ll-footer-faq {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
}

.ll-footer-newsletter p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #8b8b8b;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.ll-subscription {
  max-width: 300px;
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .ll-subscription {
    max-width: 300px;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

.ll-subscription form {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.ll-subscription form button {
  border: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  /*gradient*/
  background: #ca4989;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #ca4989, #df63c0 60%);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ca4989, #df63c0 60%);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  /*end gradient*/
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #404044;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #404044;
}

.ll-flex {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.ll-subscription form input {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 43px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #646F79;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
  border-right: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

.ll-subscription form input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.ll-socialmedia {
  margin-top: 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.ll-socialmedia a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ll-socialmedia a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ll-socialmedia a.social-facebook {
  /*gradient*/
  background: #2156C2;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, #2156C2, #5072BB 70%);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #2156C2, #5072BB 70%);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  /*end gradient*/
}

.ll-socialmedia a.social-twitter {
  /*gradient*/
  background: #1B95E0;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, #1B95E0, #1DA1F2 70%);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #1B95E0, #1DA1F2 70%);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  /*end gradient*/
}

.ll-socialmedia a.social-instagram {
  /*gradient*/
  background: #DD4B3E;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, #DD4B3E, #F11B07 70%);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #DD4B3E, #F11B07 70%);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  /*end gradient*/
}

.ll-socialmedia a.social-googleplus {
  /*gradient*/
  background: #F90731;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, #F90731, #AF1E37 70%);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #F90731, #AF1E37 70%);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  /*end gradient*/
}

.ll-socialmedia a.social-pinterest {
  /*gradient*/
  background: #BD0A1D;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, #BD0A1D, #AF1E37 70%);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #BD0A1D, #AF1E37 70%);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  /*end gradient*/
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .ll-socialmedia {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .ll-footer-about {
    position: relative;
  }
  .ll-footer-about:after {
    content: '';
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 20%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  .ll-footer-about p {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="mainfooter-area">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mx-md-5">

      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="ll-footer-about text-center text-md-left">
          <h2>About</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid animi aut cumque eligendi exercitationem molestiae molestias natus nisi odio officia perspiciatis quo repellendus saepe soluta sunt suscipit, tenetur! Commodi, distinctio.</p>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur ducimus, odit tempora ullam Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, ipsam. Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, quas!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="ll-footer-ourcompany text-md-left text-center pl-0">
          <h2>Our Company</h2>
          <a href="">How to join us</a>
          <a href="">How it work</a>
          <a href="">Buying and Selling</a>
          <a href="">Testimonial</a>
          <a href="">Copyright Notice</a>
          <a href="">Refund Policy</a>
          <a href="">Affiliates</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="ll-footer-faq text-md-left text-center pl-0">
          <h2>Help and Faq</h2>
          <a href="">How to join us</a>
          <a href="">How it work</a>
          <a href="">Buying and Selling</a>
          <a href="">Testimonial</a>
          <a href="">Copyright Notice</a>
          <a href="">Refund Policy</a>
          <a href="">Affiliates</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 text-md-left text-center">
        <h2>Subscribe</h2>
        <div class="ll-footer-newsletter">
          <p>Subscribe to get the latest news, update and offer <br/> information. Don't worry, we won't send spam!
          </p>

          <!--Footer Newsletter Subscription-->
          <div class="ll-subscription">
            <form autocomplete="off" action="/subscribe" method="post">
              <div class="ll-flex">
                <div style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
                  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john@example.com">
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: -20px;">
                  <button type="submit" disabled="disabled">&#8594;</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!--End Footer Newsletter Subscription-->

          <!--Footer Social Media-->
          <div class="ll-socialmedia">
            <a class="social-facebook" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a class="social-twitter" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a class="social-instagram" href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a class="social-googleplus" href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            <a class="social-pinterest" href=""><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a>
          </div>
          <!--End Footer Social Media-->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does you mean right bar, the content you have looks fluid.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to use to target specific devices with known widths.

```
@media (min-width:600px) and (max-width:961px)
```

Comment: 600 and 961 for which device?

Comment: tablet portrait and landscape

Comment: Not really , Tablet and Portrait Landscapes are from `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) { }`  [Details Here](https://gist.github.com/momin-ctg/7976dffb9d3347ca6cc144e6be7eae47)